# In BST, which traversal is required to visit all keys in decreasing order, assuming as a comparator?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, comparator

In BST, which traversal is required to visit all keys in decreasing order, assuming as a comparator?
The answer is Reverse In- 
And I was wondering why this is the case.

And what if it is to visit all keys in increasing order, 
what would be the answer from the following?
1. In- 2.Pre-  3.Post-  4. Reverse In- 5. Reverse Pre- 6. Reverse Post-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the left subtree contains elements smaller than the root and the right subtree elements larger than the root.

To answer your second question first: it would be infix traversal. This first visits the left (smaller) child recursively, then the item itself, then the right (larger) child recursively. It should not be hard to see that this method visits all elements in ascending order.

But then visiting all items in descending order must do the reverse of this, hence the reverse infix. This would first recursively visit the larger elements, then the element itself, then recursively the smaller elements.

Answer (score 0):

Infix traversal will print the keys in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

In-order means left-root-right(increasing).

```
void ascending(BST* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;
    ascending(root->left);
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
    ascending(root->right);
}
```

You can also do right-root-left(Reverse In for decreasing). It’s just the way of traversal, that’s it!!

```
void descending(BST* root)
{
    if(root == NULL) return;
    descending(root->right);
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
    descending(root->left);
}
```